# MNBottomPulltorefresh is creating arcproblem?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I need to implement pulltorefresh at the bottom of the table view. So I decided to use `MNBottomPullToRefresh` available in [github](https://github.com/emenegro/MNMBottomPullToRefresh). But I am not using ARC. Currently that build is using that.

> mnMBottomPullToRefresh · GitHub. But when I am implementing I am getting an error like 
>   synthesze of weak property is only allowed at ARC

Can anybody help me in how to remove this?. Because I am not well known towards ARC concept.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources, find all MNM framework files there and add the flag *-fobjc-arc* to them.